# Display image along with other content

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

In my application, Smartcard information is read and parsed which gives all information as byte [].

For displaying user information along with signature gives issue. Signature is a byte[] which I converted to Base64 encoded string(it's a tiff format) and set it in value object and render it using jsf xhtml tags.

Chrome and firefox does not display the image(encoded). But IE 8 & above does.

**Partial snippet**

```
<h:graphicImage id="cardImageId" value="data:image/png;base64,#{cardPublicDataBean.cardHolderDetail.signatureBase64}" alt="TIFF format is supported by this browser!" />
```

interpreted as(can't post whole encoded string, since it's real time data)

```
<img alt="TIFF format is supported by this browser!" src="data:image/tiff;base64,SUkqAAgBAAAyA6ma1giPJ9+ZK9f9fC/.... />
```

I tried alternative, using servlet to flush outputstream

```
<h:graphicImage value="/app/ImageServlet" />
```

Still Chrome and firefox does not display image.

Is there any other way, I can achieve this??

Using JSF 2.0, Primefaces 3.5 and Spring for my application.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your managed bean code.